# How easy is to sell your art as NFT and make money and does it have to be an interesting art OR rather a unique art?

Tags: nft, cryptography

I'm new to cryptocurrency and NFT. (Please correct me where I have misunderstood something. I am making some assumptions too)

---

Now I'm hearing everyone around me talking about NFT. I couldn't resist so I watched a couple of videos online about how to create your wallet, add money and then create NFT by paying those listing fee etc.

Now, I make pencil sketches and sometimes digital illustrations. It's a hobby, not a profession.

But now that I'm hearing about NFT a lot, I wonder if I can also earn money from it or not.

So my question is:

**How easy/tough is to sell the NFT? And does it have to actually an *interesting* art or being *unique* is the only thing required to be sold?**

I don't mind if I have a final profit (subtracting all those listing fee and commissions) for one NFT is **$5** or **$50**. As long as I have some profit I would consider it a benefit.

---

Now I know I can pretty easily create a *unique* artwork. Almost every pencil sketch or digital illustration has something unique in it. No one can create a 100% same artwork unless you digitally copy it. So that way, selling it should be no problem.

For example, I would go to a forest and take a photo, it would become *unique* automatically. Some other photographer can go to same forest and never he will get same pixels in the photo that I had got. It can be 99.99% same but not 100%.

So I really want to know, does it have to be actually *interesting*? Will I need some audience/views on it? *(just like we get on YouTube channel videos, where once we have a lot of views, only then we start earning money)*

---

I googled about it but couldn't find any good information. All they talk like is if you're an artist you can earn money using NFT. Nobody talks if your artworks needs a lot of views or it has to be interesting/creative art actually or not.

In other words, I don't know whether you have to be actually a good artist or being *unique* is the only key, no matter how boring and how below average is the stuff you create.

Comment: It is a bubble, sure there are some nft that sell a lot at high prices, but most won't sell at all. Sure big brands, famous artist, early nfts are sought by buyers. Don't blindly follow the hype, take a look at some markets like OpenSea, Rarible, etc. Some of them allow you to upload your nfts and only pay the fees after you sell them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge misconception about NFT, and I can answer it in one sentence - **in 9 cases out of 10, art doesn't matter.**

See, there is a reason why private collections from non-famous people can't do anything. Just look at this from investors POV, someone is asking you to invest in their collection but you have no opportunity to resell it and make a margin. Why would you spend your money on this? Isn't it better to go and invest in huge community projects with proportionally huge opportunities to make money?

The current trend is collections with 10K items, and huge marketing that usually stands on no use case whatsoever (All tho, there are some honest projects with utilities, games, etc. Let's don't boil them in the same pot). But the trick here is that projects are writing simple minting smart contracts, this way user has to pay for the minting price and not the project owner. (Otherwise, minting 10K would cost an unimaginable amount of ETH in fees). This is the case I mentioned above, all the investors prefer investing in this kind of collection because they have the reselling opportunity because it is a big market, compared to little to unknown private collections.

**To conclude, please stay away from it. At the current state of NFT technology - it is a purely manipulated asset, oriented on making money and not appreciating the art or keeping the ownership.**